# SQL Sum over not bounded by where clauses

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sum

I am using the SUM Over the first time and have the following query noe:

```
SELECT Id, Amount, Date, TotalAmount = SUM(Amount) OVER (order by Amount)
FROM Account
WHERE Date >= '2016-03-01' AND Date <= '2016-03-10' AND UserId = 'xyz'
ORDER BY ValutaDate
```

The `TotalAmount` should be a running total over the whole table for a specific user (so the Sum Over clause should respect the where clause for the user). On the other hand I just need a few records and not the whole table, thats why I added the where clause specifying the date range. But now, of course, my sum gets calculated just for the range I specified.

What should I do, to get just a few records specified by date range but get the sum calculated over the whole table though. Is there an performant way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the running total into its own query

```
; WITH all_rows_one_user as (SELECT *
       , TotalAmount = SUM(Amount) OVER (order by ValutaDate) 
    FROM Account
    WHERE UserId = 'xyz')
SELECT Id, Amount, Date, TotalAmount
FROM all_rows_one_user
WHERE Date >= '2016-03-01' AND Date <= '2016-03-10'
ORDER BY ValutaDate
```

Same query, different syntax:

```
SELECT Id, Amount, Date, TotalAmount
FROM (SELECT *
       , TotalAmount = SUM(Amount) OVER (order by ValutaDate) 
    FROM Account
    WHERE UserId = 'xyz') AS all_rows_one_user
WHERE Date >= '2016-03-01' AND Date <= '2016-03-10'
ORDER BY ValutaDate
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great. Any hints which indexes should I add that I am not running in performance issues?

Answer (score 1):

The WHERE clause is applied first so the SUM can't access rows that don't match that.
You can use apply though. Note it will be reading the entire table for that user so might not perform too well without a decent index.

```
SELECT a.Id, a.Amount, a.Date, ta.TotalAmount
FROM Account a
OUTER APPLY (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN a2.Date <= Account.Date THEN a2.TotalAmount ELSE 0 END) AS TotalAmount FROM Account a2 WHERE a2.UserId = Account.UserId) ta
WHERE a.Date >= '2016-03-01' AND a.Date <= '2016-03-10' AND a.UserId = 'xyz'
```

Comment: Does this query give running total?

Comment: @FLICKER good point, no it didn't. Missed that! Have updated query, thanks. Relies on Date being unique per userid though.